# how to refresh listview on a fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I need your help

I have a listview (BaseAdapter) (I fill it with SQLite) on a fragment, this fragment is on pageViewer with Swipe.
Also, There is a button on ActionBar, when I click on the button, this download the data (external SQLServer) and I sync with SQLite.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4wDp.png)

My question:

How can when I click on the button the listview refresh/update visually it on the activity?

Comment: Easy if you use a CursorAdapter for the ListView's adapter and use LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html. This means adopting a ContentProvider to allow the CursorLoader to know about data changes, but that isn't hard to implement with all the libraries out there that will do this for you (SimpleSQLConfig is one of them)

Comment: I use a BaseAdapter with ListView

Answer (score 0):

its simple as you can set the adapter for the listview on click of the download data button and call the notifydatasetchanged method for the adapter.

```
package com.example.alarmapp2;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private ImageView addButton;
    private TextView tvDate;
    private TimePicker tvTime;
    private EditText message;
    private Button save, cancel;
    private DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
    private ListView alarmListView;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;
    private static MainActivity inst;
    public static MainActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        alarmListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_list);
        addButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //setting data to list view 
        addListDetails();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.addButton:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            // setting layout view
            View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alaram_popup, null, false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
            tvDate = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.select_date);
            tvDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvTime = (TimePicker) promptView.findViewById(R.id.select_time);
            /*tvTime.setOnClickListener(this);*/
            tvTime.setIs24HourView(true);
            message = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            save = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            cancel = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            alertDialog.show();
            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (tvDate.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        tvDate.setError("Select Date");
                    } /*else if (tvTime.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        tvTime.setError("Select Date");
                    } */else if (message.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        message.setError("Select Date");
                    } else {
                        String timeMin="";
                        dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        if(tvTime.getCurrentMinute()<10){
                            timeMin="0"+tvTime.getCurrentMinute();
                        }else{
                            timeMin=""+tvTime.getCurrentMinute();
                        }
                        AlarmDoa doa = new AlarmDoa();
                        doa.setDate(tvDate.getText().toString());
                        doa.setTime(tvTime.getCurrentHour()+":"+timeMin);
                        doa.setMessage(message.getText().toString());
                        long Status=dbhelper.addalarm(doa);
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        if(Status!=0){
                            //settin data on click of button 
                            addListDetails();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            setAlarm(tvDate.getText().toString(),tvTime.getCurrentHour()+":"+tvTime.getCurrentMinute(),message.getText().toString());
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm Can't Be Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.select_date:
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String[] data = df.format(c.getTime()).split("-");
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, onDate, Integer.parseInt(data[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(data[1]), Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePicker.show();
            break;
        case R.id.select_time:
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

            TimePickerDialog timePicker=new TimePickerDialog(this, onTime, c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
            timePicker.show();
            break;
        }
    }

    protected void setAlarm(String date, String time, String msg) {
        manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("date", ""+date);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("time", ""+time);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("msg", ""+msg);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        String[] data=time.split(":");
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt( data[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt( data[1]));
        Log.d("calendar.getTimeInMillis()", ""+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        Log.d("System", ""+calendar.getTime());
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "ALarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    OnDateSetListener onDate = new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String month="";
            if(monthOfYear<9){
                month= "0"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1);
            }else{
                month=String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1);
            }
            tvDate.setText( pad(dayOfMonth)+ "-" +  month+ "-" + String.valueOf(year));

        }
    };
    OnTimeSetListener onTime= new OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            //tvTime.setText(pad(hourOfDay) + ":" + pad(minute));
        }
    };
    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    private void addListDetails() {
        dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        AlarmAdapter adapter= new AlarmAdapter(MainActivity.this, dbhelper.getAlarmList());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        alarmListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use a BaseAdapter with ListView

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated; use AppCompatActivity please